# Simple Java Calculator without limit of numbers to be operated

Tags: java, calculator

So I'm super new to programming and java, a colleague sent me this challenge to build a simple calculator with all four operation (+, - , / , *) but for only too integers.

Now he's asked me to remove this limit of only two values.
(i.e. 10+20+10+12 = 52 )

how difficult is that, should I be learning this right now ?

````
    public class Calculadora {
    private int numero1;
    private int numero2;
    private int resultado;

    public int soma(){
        this.setResultado(numero1 + numero2);
        return this.resultado;
    }

    public static int soma(final int numero1, final int numero2){
        return numero1 + numero2;
    }

    public int subtrai(){
        this.setResultado(numero1 - numero2);
        return this.resultado;
    }

    public static int subtrai(final int numero1, final int numero2){
        return numero1 - numero2;
    }

    public int multiplica(){
        this.setResultado(numero1 * numero2);
        return this.resultado;
    }

    public static int multiplica(final int numero1, final int numero2){
        return numero1 * numero2;
    }

    public int divisao(){
        this.setResultado(numero1 / numero2);
        return this.resultado;
    }

    public static int divisao(final int numero1, final int numero2){
        return (numero1 / numero2);
    }

    public int getNumero1() {
        return numero1;
    }

    public void setNumero1(int numero1) {
        this.numero1 = numero1;
    }

    public int getNumero2() {
        return numero2;
    }

    public void setNumero2(int numero2) {
        this.numero2 = numero2;
    }

    public int getResultado() {
        return resultado;
    }

    private void setResultado(int resultado){
        this.resultado = resultado;
    } ```
````

Comment: That would be much more complicated. You would need to read the whole string, split it in operators and operands, consider order of operation, build an operation tree and execute it.

Comment: It isn't very difficult but I'd recommend reading into method overloading for this. That way you can call the same method but depending on how many arguments you pass it will still work with 2,3 or 4 numbers.

Comment: What's your problem with this code?

Comment: I think a Tree is a good data structure for this. Though trees are pretty advanced, you could look into them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html):

```
public Integer sum(Integer... numbers) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Integer number : numbers) {
        sum += number;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look in to the following topics:

infix, postfix, prefix, and the Stack class. That is the essence of evaluating and
processing mathematical expressions of arbitrary length.

Answer (score 0):

If you just use + or - look into ArrayList ArrList... you can add all your operands with ArrList.add( input integer here) an use a for loop to add them: for (into i=0;i<ArrList.length();i++) 
 {
 result +=ArrList[i];
}
 If you use / and × you would have to sort your operands after the weight of your operators:2+3+4×2 , to use a loop you would have to record it to: (.4×2)+3+2
Note: If, for my first case, you got like 3-4 you would ad them ad Arr[0]=3 and Arr[1]=-3.